# Is there any way to mensure Apple Search Ads Revenue and Ad Cost on GA4?

Tags: ios, apple-search-ads

For a while, I am trying to discover how I can mensure Apple Search Ads Revenue and Ad Cost on GA4.

If someone know how, it will be amazing!

Thanks,

Ad Cost: I tried Ad Cost Import by CSV on GA4 - that not worked.
Revenue: the events on Firebase track some Revenue, but I'm sure they are 100% accurate.